# Google People API - Birthday - Date object is not returned in GET requests

Tags: google-people-api

In Google People - [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) and other GET APIs, the Date object of Birthday field is not returned for some Contacts. Have authenticated with the full People scope [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts].

We also do not know the format of the "text" field to parse that, as the param can have any random string.

How to parse the birthday of a user? When will the Date object not be returned?

**Sample Request**

https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?pageSize=100&requestSyncToken=true&personFields=birthdays

**Sample response Birthdays**

```
    {
        "birthdays": [
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "source": {
                        "id": "3ebd95668aeed9d7",
                        "type": "CONTACT"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                },
                "text": "2000-07-24"
            }
        ],
        "resourceName": "people/c4520933868599957975",
        "etag": "<etag>"
    },
    {
        "birthdays": [
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "source": {
                        "id": "5f5712ce0861c5b0",
                        "type": "CONTACT"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                },
                "text": "1880-03-11"
            }
        ],
        "resourceName": "people/c6869980432690169264",
        "etag": "<etag>"
    },
    {
        "birthdays": [
            {
                "date": {
                    "month": 1,
                    "year": 1990,
                    "day": 26
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "source": {
                        "id": "a16dde58e814a36",
                        "type": "CONTACT"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                },
                "text": "01/26/1990"
            }
        ],
        "resourceName": "people/c727012367875000886",
        "etag": "<etag>"
    },
    {
        "birthdays": [
            {
                "date": {
                    "month": 1,
                    "year": 1998,
                    "day": 1
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "source": {
                        "id": "f350f568dd11db1",
                        "type": "CONTACT"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                },
                "text": "Jan 1, 1998"
            }
        ],
        "resourceName": "people/c1095798948755479985",
        "etag": "<etag>"
    },
    {
        "birthdays": [
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "source": {
                        "id": "3652e00f0d28c9f4",
                        "type": "CONTACT"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                },
                "text": "random string accept"
            }
        ],
        "resourceName": "people/c3914437381388290548",
        "etag": "<etag>"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hello, could you include the scopes you are using ?

Comment: Using the full scope - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.
I will add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

The [birthday](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#birthday) field, can take both Date or text, and are not guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: Yes, that's fine but the Date object is not returned in few contacts.

Comment: Yes, because Date is not a required field. the method only requires text **OR** Date. So that means that for those Birthdays which had no Date field, it will not be returned.

Comment: So in those cases where Date object is not sent, how can we parse the text field? [Taking into account that text can be any random string].

Comment: I guess you have to build a parser that takes that into account. Or you could perhaps request all birthdays in a list and add them to your users using Domain Wide Authorization

Comment: That's not possible, as we have to run Google People full sync every week and the birthdays would disappear again. Then we would have extra request every week. 
Our solution, for now, is that we have added handling for most of the predictable date formats. We will incrementally add if we come across any unhandled format.